# Как регулярным выражением убрать подпись?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть переменная которая содержит строку

```
$posttext =  '<p><strong>Вступайте в сообщество «<noindex>Новости Энска</noindex>»</strong> </p>';
```

вот эту строку из переменной мне и нужно удалить.
Она не имеет переносов, просто всегда отличается разным количество пробелов кавычек наличием/отсутствием `strong`
неизменны в ней два словосочетания: "Вступайте в сообщество" "Новости Энска"
пишу вот такое регулярное выражение но не срабатывает:

```
$posttext = preg_replace('/<p>([^А-я]*)Вступайте в сообщество(.*)p>/', '', $posttext);
```

То есть по смыслу должно получиться следующее:

Если в абзаце встречается словосочетание "Вступайте в сообщество", то нужно удалить все символы до и после этого словосочетания включая `<p>`.

Comment: скинь строку убранную и первичную

Comment: Вот это целиком надо убрать? `<p><strong>Вступайте в сообщество «<noindex>Новости Энска</noindex>»</strong> </p>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то это мне кажется подойдет вам:

```
$posttext = preg_replace('#(\<p\>)(((?!\<\/p\>).)*)(Вступайте в сообщество)(((?!\<\/p\>).)*)(\<\/p\>)#s', '', $posttext);
```

Я несколько проверок сделал, если не подойдет или я не правильно понял вопрос скажите обновлю ответ.

Comment: все работает спасибо)) и мой вариант оказывается работал, просто почему то в данном участке функции, которая чистит от грязи срабатывать не хотел, поднял на пару строк выше и заработало)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

> Если в абзаце встречается словосочетание "Вступайте в сообщество", то
>   нужно удалить все символы до и после этого словосочетания включая `<p>`.

Эмм... Если нашли включение строки "Вступайте в сообщество" в исходную, то и заменяйте сразу на эту же строку...

```
$posttext = '<p><strong>Вступайте в сообщество «<noindex>Новости Энска</noindex>»</strong> </p>';
if (strpos($posttext, 'Вступайте в сообщество') !== false) {
    $posttext = 'Вступайте в сообщество';
}
```

Comment: я вот тоже не понял в чем проблема у автора и зачем тут регулярки :)

Comment: или я вас не понял или вы меня))
у меня есть переменная $posttext в которой содержится текст статьи. Так вот из текста статьи мне нужно удалить вот эту часть
<p><strong>Вступайте в сообщество «<noindex>Новости Энска</noindex>»</strong> </p>

Comment: Единственное, по какой причине нужна регулярка - строка находится в тегах `<p>...</p>`, но содержимое не всегда такое, что указано в условии.
А если, строка не меняется, то, конечно, регулярка здесь будет лишней.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
$posttext = preg_replace_callback('~<p>.*?</p>~', function ($matches) {
    return strpos($matches[0], 'Вступайте в сообщество') ? 'Вступайте в сообщество' : $matches[0];
}, $posttext);
```

Вариант 2:

```
$posttext = preg_replace('~<p>.*?Вступайте в сообщество.*?</p>~', 'Вступайте в сообщество', $posttext);
```

Однако, обе регулярки, на мой взгляд, не являются оптимальными, но они простые.

Answer (score 0):

Тестировал на разных вариантах строк с тегом/без stong и с разным количеством пробелов и кавычек, вот что получилось:

```
$posttext = preg_replace('\s*<p>\s*(<strong>)?\s*(Вступайте в сообщество)\s*[«]+\s*<noindex>\s*(Новости Энска)\s*</noindex>\s*[»]+\s*(</strong>)?\s*</p>\s*', '', $posttext);
```